# Custom Business Powerpoint or word document template to be used in powerpoint and word in O365 Sharepoint

Tags: document-template

My requirement is when a user clicks to open a PowerPoint or Word document from a SharePoint document library. It should display all the business templates of my organization.

Whenever I create a document library those templates should reside inside the PowerPoint or Word document. It should be applicable on any sites created under that O365 SharePoint.

Example: Any SharePoint site → Document library → Click New → PowerPoint document should display my custom business template.

Note: If I add any new template or change an existing business template that too should be populated. Could you please assist me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Using Organization assets option we can achieve.
Using HUB Content type publishing we can achieve.
using these 2 options we can achieve it.